# Reactive forms patchValue() with ngValue not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have one dropdown in reactive forms I have used the whole object as the value(`{NAME:'test',CODE:'002'}`) for further processing, its working fine I am able to get selected item in .ts file.In edit mode, I have to bind selected item to drown using patchValue but it's not working.

html

```
                     <select class="form-group form-control" formControlName="county">
                                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                                <option *ngFor="let item of countyDataset" [ngValue]='item'>{{item.NAME}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
```

.ts code

```
bindDataValue(){
    const rec=county{
         CODE: "028"
          NAME: "LOS ALAMOS"
       }
this.form.patchValue(rec);
}
```

Comment: By any chance, did you find a solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <select class="form-group form-control" formControlName="county">
                            <option value="">-Select-</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let item of countyDataset" [ngValue]='item'>{{item.NAME}}
                            </option>
                        </select>



  bindDataValue(){
        const rec=county{
             CODE: "028"
              NAME: "LOS ALAMOS"
           }
     this.form.patchValue({ county: rec })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old question, but, when we use [ngValue] we need take account that we are working with object. So the value should be the **same** object

```
  countries: any = [
      {full: "Great Britain", short: "GB"},
      ...
 ]

 this.selectForm = this.fb.group({
      selectedCountryControl: []
    })
 const country=this.countries.find(x=>x.short=='US')
 this.selectForm.patchValue({selectedCountryControl: country})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  <h1>Reactive Forms</h1>
    


<div style="padding: 0 0 20px 20px">
  
    <h3>Value string</h3>
    <form [formGroup]="selectForm">
    <select
  name="countryReactiveString"
  formControlName="selectedCountryControl"
  placeholder="Country"
  [compareWith]="compareFn"
>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
    {{ country?.full }}
  </option>
</select>
    </form>
    {{selectForm.value | json}}
  </div>


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  selectForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  
  countries: any = [
    {
      full: "Great Britain",
      short: "GB"
    },
    {
      full: "United States",
      short: "US"
    },
    {
      full: "Canada",
      short: "CA"
    }
  ];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectForm = this.fb.group({
      selectedCountryControl: []
    })
    this.selectForm.patchValue({
       selectedCountryControl: {
    full: 'United States',
    short: 'US',
  }
    })
  }

compareFn(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 && (c1.short === c2.short || c2 === c1.short);
  }
    
    }
```

Here is demo it should work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-d7edt6